# Search functionality in a d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a forced-directed graph.

Below is the format of the **JSON data**

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([
  ["1000000000039214051", "1000000000336563307", "Customer", "Customer", "2016-06-21 01:32:42", "2016-06-21 02:39:45", 155.4492950439453, 4],
  ["1000000000039214051", "10000000682705", "Customer", "Agent", "2016-08-16 23:12:24", "2016-08-17 05:08:22", 171.84144592285156, 3],
  ["04144221227", "1000000000060220197", "Phone", "Customer", "2016-01-04 03:41:13", "2016-01-05 01:54:03", 264.75457763671875, 4],
  ["10000000490503", "1000000000060220197", "Agent", "Customer", "2016-10-21 03:39:50", "2016-10-21 06:59:41", 26.845823287963867, 4],
  ["1000000000218556629", "600169462257", "Customer", "Phone", "2016-10-05 21:51:01", "2016-10-06 02:41:32", 76.26348876953125, 4],
  ["10000000486511", "2000000000212907929", "Agent", "Customer", "2016-11-13 23:33:38", "2016-11-14 01:30:13", 114.56245422363281, 3],
  ["CHB445789", "1000000000313013892", "ID_Card", "Customer", "2016-01-04 01:50:38", "2016-01-04 08:12:44", 457.4786071777344, 4],
  ["10000000499929", "2000000000144964466", "Agent", "Customer", "2016-09-01 05:01:45", "2016-09-04 03:44:10", 121.28453826904297, 1],
  ["2000000000180876855", "2000000000249424289", "Customer", "Customer", "2016-05-23 05:03:58", "2016-05-23 08:35:11", 218.06622314453125, 1],..])
```

I parse through this dynamic JSON data as follows:

```
var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
var startnodes = [];
var endnodes = [];
var startnodetype = [];
var endnodetype = [];
var SendTime = [];
var PayTime = [];
var Total_Amt = [];
var Depth = [];
galData.map(function(e, i) {
  startnodes.push(e[0]);
  endnodes.push(e[1]);
  startnodetype.push(e[2]);
  endnodetype.push(e[3]);
  SendTime.push(e[4]);
  PayTime.push(e[5]);
  Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
  Depth.push(e[7]);
});
var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth);
makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);
```

Below is the **createNodes** function that makes the nodes and links for the **makeGraph** function:

```
function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth) {
      var node_set = [];
      var links = [];
      var nodetype = d3.set();
      startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
        var tgt = endnodes[i];
        if (!node_set.find(function(d) {
            return d.id == src
          })) {
          node_set.push({
            id: src,
            type: startnodetype[i]
          });
        }
        if (!node_set.find(function(d) {
            return d.id == tgt
          })) {
          node_set.push({
            id: tgt,
            type: endnodetype[i]
          });
        }
    
        links.push({
          source: src,
          target: tgt,
          sendtime: SendTime[i],
          paytime: PayTime[i],
          total_amt: Total_Amt[i],
          depth: Depth[i],
          value: 1
        });
      });
    
      startnodetype.forEach(function(src, i) {
        var tgt_type = endnodetype[i];
        nodetype.add(src);
        nodetype.add(tgt_type);
      });
    
      var d3GraphData = {
        nodes: node_set.map(function(d) {
          return {
            id: d.id,
            type: d.type,
            group: 1
          }
        }),
        links: links,
        nodetype: nodetype.values().map(function(d) {
          return {
            id: d.id,
            group: 1
          }
        })
      }
      return d3GraphData;
    
};
```

Now, I am trying to implement search functionality in my d3.js graph. User can enter a node "Id" in the search field and everything else apart from the selected node would have the opacity set to 0 for

```
duration(5000)
```

And back to 1 after that.

All the nodes have the property.

```
d.id
```

Below is the **HTML** and the **event listener**

```
    <input type = "text" id="node"/>
    <button id ="search">
    Search_Node
    </button>
 var myBtn = document.getElementById("search");

 myBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    //find the node
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("node").value;
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
    if (selectedVal == "none") {
        node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
    } else {
        var selected = node.filter(function (d) {
            return d.id != selectedVal;
        });
        selected.style("opacity", "0");
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        link.style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .style("opacity", 1);
    }
});
```

I do not see any errors, but when I try and type in the Node Id that exists, the feature does not work, and nothing happens.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/2rrkyz9t/18/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/7fxvvz8d/

The issue was that you were selecting the node group not the circles

```
var node = svg.append("g")// you were selecting this
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")// instead of this
  .attr("class", "node") // so I added a class to make it easier
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.type);
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(600)
      .style("opacity", .8);
    tooltip.html(d.id + "<p/>type:" + d.type)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
  })

  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));
```

and the same goes for links

```
var link = svg.append("g")// you were selecting the group
  .attr("class", "links")// by this class
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(d3GraphData.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("class", "link") // added a class on the lines

  .on('mouseover', function(d) {

    var thisSource = d.source.id,
      thisTarget = d.target.id;
    var filteredLinks = d3GraphData.links.filter(function(e) {
      return (e.source.id === thisSource && e.target.id === thisTarget) || (e.source.id === thisTarget && e.target.id === thisSource);
    });
```

In the button event:

```
myBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  //find the node
  var selectedVal = document.getElementById('node').value;
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node"); // you selected the group
  if (selectedVal == "none") {
    node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
  } else {
    var selected = node.filter(function (d) {
      return d.id != selectedVal;
    });
    selected.style("opacity", "0");
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")// same here
    link.style("opacity", "0");
    d3.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()  // and here
      .duration(5000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
});
```

I modified it to this:

```
myBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  //find the node
  var selectedVal = document.getElementById('node').value;
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node"); // select the circles
  if (selectedVal == "none") {
    node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
  } else {
    var selected = node.filter(function (d) {
      return d.id == selectedVal;
    });

    node.style("opacity", 0); // hide all nodes
    selected.style("opacity", 1)// but this one
      .attr("fill", "red");// just for the effect

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .style("opacity", 0);// hide all links
    // and then show them all again after some time
    node.transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
    link.transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton . I was real close but this class thing was new. Is it possible to make this search feature work with other filters?

Comment: Yep, you were really close indeed! Glad I helped. As for the filter, do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/dw6wb3ow/ ?

Comment: This is awesome.. Really appreciated. The search feature works fine with all filters except for the checkboxes one, which control the opacity.. It acts weird with that filter. If for instance I select "Customer" and "ID_Card", they become opaque and every thing else has 0 opacity. Then I try and search for instance either a "Customer" or "ID_Card", then it just falls apart and does not work as intended.

Comment: You have to synchronize all your filters and decide what you want to do when e.g. Customer is not shown and someone searches with the id of a customer. A not very good implementation of what rules I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/zc2ehr9L/ . Also, you could add one attribute on each node like this `node.hidden=false` and instead of the filtered list you use/ update this field - and opacity accordingly.

Comment: The only problem i noticed is when the fiddle runs initially there are some orphaned nodes of type **ID_Card** that are not connected to anything for some reason..otherwise it seemed to work

Comment: Hi Maria..seems like the unchecking of nodes seems to work fine and makes the unchecked nodes not visible.. But rechecking them does not seem to work well..tried playing with the code but no luck..posted another question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558545/d3-js-multiple-filters-for-opacity-not-working-together-as-intended.