# D3.js Opacity filters partially working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, checkbox

I have a solid d3.js graph that works well for the most part.  There are 4 node types:

```
     Agent,Customer,Phone,ID_Card
```

There are checkboxes that handle the opacity of the nodes and links. If **Agent** and **Customer** are checked then the 2 nodes and all possible links between them are opaque. And rest of the graph has

```
 opacity(0)
```

Also, there is a **Search** feature , which lets the user search through the graph with the below node attribute

```
    d.id
```

A node for which the input ID matches , will stay opaque and the rest of the graph will fade out for a few seconds

Below is the **HTML**

```
          <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" value="Agent"> type=Agent</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" value="Customer"> type=Customer</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" value="Phone"> type=Phone</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" value="ID_Card"> type=ID_Card</label>
  <br />

 <input type="text" id="node" />
  <button id="search">
    Search_Node
  </button>
</div>
```

Below is the **javascript** code that ensures that all the filters work well together in tandem.

For instance , if **Customer** and **Phone** are checked and if the **Search** feature is applied to search either a Customer or a Phone , the remaining two nodes that were unchecked will still remain at

```
   opacity(0)
```

And the search will be applied only to the sub graph.

```
  d3.selectAll("input[name=checkb]").on("change", function() {
    function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
      var checkboxesChecked = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].defaultValue);
        }

      }
      return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : " ";
    }

    var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkb");

    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", 1);

    node.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.type) === -1;
      })
      .style("opacity", "0");

    link.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.source.type) === -1 ||
          checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.target.type) === -1;
      })
      .style("opacity", "0");

    link.filter(function(d) {
        return checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.source.type) > -1 &&
          checkedBoxes.indexOf(d.target.type) > -1;
      })
      .style("opacity", "1");


  });

  // get the checkboxes
  var typeAgentChk = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Agent"]')[0];
  var typeCustomerChk = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Customer"]')[0];
  var typePhoneChk = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Phone"]')[0];
  var typeIDCardChk = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="ID_Card"]')[0];

  var checkBoxes = [typeAgentChk, typeCustomerChk, typePhoneChk, typeIDCardChk];
  var nodeTypes = ["Agent", "Customer", "Phone", "ID_Card"];


  var filterByCheckBox = function(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
      // filter
      filterBy("type", el.value, false);
    } else {
      removeFilterFor("type", el.value);
    }
  }

  var removeFilterFor = function(attribute, value) {
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
    var selected = node.filter(function(d) { // filter by attribute/value
        return d[attribute] == value;
      })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .each(function(d) {
        var index = filtered.indexOf(d.id);
        if (index > -1) {
          filtered.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
  }
  var filterBy = function(attribute, value, restoreAll, highlightSelected) {
    // get nodes and links - could be moved outside for efficiency
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
    if (value == "none" || value == null) { // do we need this?
      node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
    } else {
      var selected = node.filter(function(d) { // filter by attribute/value
        return d[attribute] == value;
      });

      // get any nodes we have filtered before
      var alreadyFiltered = node.filter(function(d) {
        return filtered.indexOf(d.id) > -1;
      })
      var alreadyFilteredLinks = link.filter(function(d) {
        return filtered.indexOf(d.source.id) > -1 && filtered.indexOf(d.target.id) > -1;
      })
      // hide all
      node.style("opacity", 0);
      link.style("opacity", 0);
      if (highlightSelected) {

        svg.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      }
      selected.style("opacity", 1)
        .each(function(d) { // save the id's in the filtered list
          if (filtered.indexOf(d.id) == -1) {
            filtered.push(d.id);
          }
        });

      // but the already filtered and the currently selected
      alreadyFiltered.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
      alreadyFilteredLinks.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .style("opacity", 1);



      if (restoreAll) { // restore all 
        filtered = [];
        svg.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
          .duration(5000)
          .style("opacity", 1);
      }
    }
  }



for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
    //filterByCheckBox(checkBoxes[i]); // add all ids in filtered
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      filterByCheckBox(checkBoxes[i])
    });
  }

  searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get value to filter with
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById('node').value;
    if (nodeTypes.indexOf(selectedVal) > -1) { // we filter by type
      filterBy("type", selectedVal, false);
    } else {
      console.log("filterBy", "id", selectedVal)
      filterBy("id", selectedVal, false, true);
    }
  });
```

This seems to be working as expected for the most part. The **unchecking** of checkboxes works fine and seems to make the unchecked nodes at

```
 opacity(0)
```

But when those **nodes** are checked back again , it does not seem to work well.

For instance, if **Customer** and **Phone** remained check and the other two remain unchecked, only **Customer** and **Phone** are visible. But if the **Agent** node is re-checked again , even **ID_Card** node becomes visible though it is still unchecked.

This holds true during **checking back** of any node. Even the **unchecked** node becomes visible.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/ccoc7t5a/4/)

Comment: Hi, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/nkjtjy12/ I've refactored a big part of the code in order to figure out what was wrong and I ended up changing the way visibility is stored: I added `visible` attribute to each node. Hope this helps!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkjtjy12/1/ small correction in graph reset

Comment: Update to check the checkbox if user searches by type: https://jsfiddle.net/nkjtjy12/2/